# Create algorithm in r to find the sum of some specific numbers

Tags: r, algorithm

Please i have a question, i've been trying to generate a code for this but it doesn't come to my mind a way to do it.

So i need to build a graph, and the values should go like this:

```
1  -  (1*5) + 600
2  -  (2*5) + 600
3  -  (3*5) + 600
.....
.....
.....
15 -  (15*5) + 600
16 -  (16*5) + (600*2)
17 -  (17*5) + (600*2)
.....
.....
31 -  (31*5) + (600*3)
31 -  (32*5) + (600*3)
```

And so on, till n is 10000.
So, starting from 1, then 16, then 31, 46 and so on +15. It's a little bit difficult to generate it for me. The part of multiplying 600.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
study_size<-seq(1,1000,1) 

for (i in study_size ) { 
element<-(n*5) + 600 
   }
```

Comment: What did you try by yourself, as a starting point?

Comment: well, i can get till the point where i do :
(for n=1, n<1000, n++) { (n*5) + 600 }

I get stuck at the 600 part...

Comment: It is not an `R` syntax.

Comment: i can modify the syntax, it's more of an 'algorithm', and that's what i need

Comment: study_size<-seq(1,1000,1)
for (i in study_size ) {
element<-(n*5) + 600 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R you can do this with the `rep` function, using the argument `each`:

```
n <- 10000
v1 <- 1:n
v2 <- rep(1:ceiling(n / 15), each = 15)[1:n]
result <- v1 * 5 + 600 * v2
```

Alternatively, you can use `floor` and write it avoiding the definition of `v2` as

```
result2 <- v1 * 5 + 600 * (1 + floor((v1 - 1) / 15))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, well, if i run it, i should get: 605, 610, 615 and so on, and i don't get this

Comment: Oh I thought the "-" in your question were minus signs. I'll update the answer, please update the question so that it doesn't look like subtraction

Comment: Ah no sorry, it's like the respective value for each of them

Answer (score 0):

You can use ceiling function in R.

For example multiply with

```
for(n in 1:1000){
600 * ceiling(n/15)
}
```

ceiling function will result in the next integer for example:
ceiling(0.01) = 1 and ceiling(1) = 1. you will get what u want

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
 n <- 100
 v1 <- 1:n
 res <- ((v1-1)%/%15+1)*600 +v1*5
```